# Bringing in code to a GitLab repository from an external source

Tags: nlp, gitlab, open-source

My team and I have developed an internal NLP code repository for our company. We would like to know if there are any restrictions towards bringing in external code to this repo regarding copyright/licensing requirements?

Answer (score 0):

It's a complex issue all related to what kind of license your code has and what kind of license the external code you want to bring in (and I guess redistribute) has.

Gitlab won't prevent you from doing whatever you want to do. So it's only between you and the license/licensor/licensee.. well the law :)

So I invite you to check the terms of the licenses of the external code, and clarify the license of your internal code.

Not knowing your situation in terms of licenses, I'd take a scenarion that if the external code is [GPL (GNU Public License)](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/gpl-3.0/) and you want it to be part of yours, then yours has to be under GPL as well.
This does not mean it has to be public, it means that if you distribute your work you have to do it with the entire code sources.

It also means all the authors of your code agrees to do that integration.

So this is just an example with GPL and the fact that both codes are fully integrated. But if the external tool is MIT or LGPL or/and you use it as an external library. This makes things different. That external tool licenses and your code license do not have to be correlated anymore.

So that said please verify with license terms, that's the best place to know what to do. Have a look at https://choosealicense.com they provide pretty good explanation. And if you need more support you can reach out to the [Open Research Institute](https://www.openresearch.institute/).

Good luck ;)